# eigenvectors for 2 by 2 matrices, when we have one eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

We know, that n by n matrix has n eigenvectors.

But for example i have 2 by 2 matrix A = (0;-1;1;2) - (numbers by rows).

I have got jnly one eigenvalue( lambda1 = lambda2 = -1)

As a result i have got one eigenvector = t(1,1). But according to the definition there are 2 eigenvectors in 2 by 2 matrices. What should i do in this case? How to derive the second eigenvector?

Comment: There might be a misconception or incomplete understanding on your part. Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_matrix

Comment: To be a little nitpicky:  when you say that an $n \times n$ matrix has $n$ eigenvectors, you really mean $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.  Of course, any time there's one (nonzero) eigenvector, there are infinitely many:  just scale the eigenvector by a constant.  And as the answers have pointed out, the statement is false:  an $n \times n$ matrix can have anywhere between 1 and $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors, or even none of them if you don't allow complex eigenvectors.

Comment: Also, check your calculations.  That matrix has $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = 1$, not $-1$, and its eigenvectors are multiples of $(1, -1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you see the claim that all $2\times 2$ matrices have two linearly independent eigenvectors? You just produced a counterexample. What you may remember is that *symmetric* matrices always have a full set of linearly independent eigenvectors (with real eigenvalues) but your matrix is not symmetric.

Matrices without a full set of eigenvectors are called *defective*; see for instance the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix). To form a basis the eigenvectors of a defective matrix are often augmented with "generalized" eigenvectors (danger: this term is overloaded and also has a different common meaning) but this is not what I would consider "deriving" a second eigenvector.

Comment: Thank you!
I have understood my mistake:)

Answer (score 2):

An $n\times n$ matrix does not always have $n$ eigenvectors.  For example, the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
has $1$ as an eigenvector with multiplicity $2$, but only one eigenvector, $$\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

On the other hand,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}
$$
has two eigenvectors, 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}.
$$

In general, however, a matrix determines a basis of *generalized* eigenvectors.